# How to know which Stack.Screen I'm on?

Tags: react-native, tabbar, stack-navigator

I have this Tab Screen.

```
  <Tabs.Screen
    name="Photo"
    options={{
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => null,
    }}
  >
    {() => <StackNavFactory screenName="Photo" />}
```

As you can see if I click `Photo` tab, It goes to 'StackNavFactory screenName=Photo'.

StackNavFactory has these two Stack screens.

It has `Photo` stack screen and `Comments` stack screen.

```
  {screenName === "Photo" ? (
    <Stack.Screen name="Photo" component={Photo} />
  ) : null}

  <Stack.Screen
    name="Comments"
    component={Comments}
    options={{
      headerTintColor: "white",
    }}
  />
```

Since It should go to screenName="Photo" first, when I click Photo tab, It goes to Photo Stack screen.

But if I click some button on Photo screen, I set It goes to `Comments` Stack screen on the same Photo tab.

In summary Photo tab has two stack screen Photo and Comments.

And I want to know where I'm on photo or Comments from TabBar components.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to get the focused route name. In this use case, you can use the `getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route)` function.

(Untested) example:

```js
<Tabs.Navigator
  screenOptions={({ route }) => ({
    tabBarStyle: {
      display: getFocusedRouteNameFromRoute(route) === "..." ? "..." : "...",
    },
  })}
>
  ...
</Tabs.Navigator>
```

Also, you can read [Setting parent screen options based on the child navigator's state](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/screen-options-resolution#setting-parent-screen-options-based-on-child-navigators-state) in the official documentation to learn more.

Comment: Thanks, but it shows me 'Photo' information which is the info which Tab I'm on. Not 'Comments'. I'd like to know which Stack I'm on in this Tab.
: Photo (Tab) > Comments (Stack)

Comment: @hyejung I'm not sure if I can understand your question. Please try to explain it more or try other sentences.

Comment: @hyejung Ok got it. You can apply the same exact code to the `<Stack.Navigator />` component

Comment: yes but problem is StackNavigator doesn't have `tabBarStyle` module.

Comment: I change my question for more detail. If you still don't understand my question, you can refer to it :) thanks.